# Can I use React and JSX in Javascript without installing the Node.js?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a project, which has already a webserver. The webserver runs PHP and it is limited. Many software cannot be installed.

I understand that **React does not require any installation** but [adding JSX to a project needs to run these commands](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project):

Step 1: `Run npm init -y`

Step 2: `Run npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3`

Unfortunately, I cannot add NodeJS to the webserver.

**JSX** coding syntax would be very useful for me using the JavaScript files.

## Option for adding it to HTML

I understand that I could add JSX to an HTML file:

```
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
</script>
```

But I would like to use in .js files.

## Examples

I have 2 examples:

1. Example is working but it has no JSX.
2. Example has JSX but it is not working.

The HTML file is the same.

### 1. Example project: Unexpected token error with JSX

```js
const myelement1 = <h1>JSX should work</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(
  myelement1,
  document.getElementById('reactRoot')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My React example page</h1>
    <div id="reactRoot"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

### 2. Example project: React is working without JSX

```js
const myelement2=React.createElement('h1', {}, 'No JSX!');

ReactDOM.render( myelement2, document.getElementById('reactRoot'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My React example page</h1>
    <div id="reactRoot"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

## My Question

How could I fix **1. Example project**, if no program installation is possible?

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `type` attribute as `text/babel`, this way the problems will be resolved, e.g:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div id="reactRoot"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        const myelement1 = <h1>JSX should work</h1>;

        ReactDOM.render(
            myelement1,
            document.getElementById('reactRoot')
        );
    </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need to store the JSX in .js files. This is 1 HTML file that included the JSX. Do you have any idea for a separately stored .js file?

Comment: @questionMark that does not matter, just add `type="text/babel"` to your script tag, like this: `<script type="text/babel" src="./scripts/jsx.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried your recommended script tag locally, added to the .html. It was not working. Is this working for you?

Comment: What @PS-PARSA is suggesting should work I just tested it.

Comment: @MrBrN197 I added this line to the HTML: <script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
I get this error messages in the browser console: 
1. 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/.../index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
2. 
babel.min.js:24 GET file:///C:/.../index.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: @questionMark this error is related to CORS policy, not jsx and Babbel...